# Make unfilled part of path inside an a tag clickable

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a map, on which I have placed some pins at different city locations. These pins are made with `<path>` tags. These path tags are each wrapped inside an `<a>` tag. I noticed that when I try to hover over the pins that only the filled part of the path is clickable, even though the `<a>` tag forms a square around the `<path>` tag. Is it possible to make the whole square of the  tag clickable somehow? Even when its content is a path. I tried the obvious things like adding display block to the elements, but it makes no difference.

Codepen here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBPwWp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a transparent rectangle in front of, or behind, your pin symbol.

Compare these two versions of the pin.  The second one includes a `<rect>` like this:

```
<rect ... fill="transparent"/>
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
}

.map-pin {
  fill: #CD1A1C;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="993 67 55 74">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <path id="pin-reykjavik" class="map-pin st3" d="M1019,106c-5.8-1.3-9.5-7-8.3-13c1.2-6,6.7-10,12.4-8.7c4.2,0.9,7.6,4.3,8.3,8.7
          c1.1,6-2.7,11.9-8.3,13C1021.7,106.3,1020.4,106.3,1019,106 M1021.1,67.6c-15,0-27.3,12.4-27.3,27.6c0,6,2,11.7,5.4,16.5l20.6,28.2
          c0.5,0.6,1.5,0.8,2.1,0.3c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3l20.6-28.2c3.5-4.8,5.4-10.5,5.4-16.5C1048.4,80,1036.1,67.6,1021.1,67.6">
    </path>
  </a>
</svg>


<svg viewBox="993 67 55 74">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <rect x="993" y="67" width="55" height="74" fill="transparent"/>
    <path id="pin-reykjavik" class="map-pin st3" d="M1019,106c-5.8-1.3-9.5-7-8.3-13c1.2-6,6.7-10,12.4-8.7c4.2,0.9,7.6,4.3,8.3,8.7
          c1.1,6-2.7,11.9-8.3,13C1021.7,106.3,1020.4,106.3,1019,106 M1021.1,67.6c-15,0-27.3,12.4-27.3,27.6c0,6,2,11.7,5.4,16.5l20.6,28.2
          c0.5,0.6,1.5,0.8,2.1,0.3c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3l20.6-28.2c3.5-4.8,5.4-10.5,5.4-16.5C1048.4,80,1036.1,67.6,1021.1,67.6">
    </path>
  </a>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either

1. set the CSS property `pointer-events: visible;` on the objects.

or

2. Put a hidden rect over the path with `pointer-events: all`

depending on exactly what you want to happen.

Comment: I tried setting this on both the <a> and the <path> tag, but still only the filled path is clickable.

Comment: then you need a hidden rect over the path that fills the area which can intercept clicks.

Comment: You gave me the idea to look at pointer events and I figured out that putting `pointer-events: bounding-box;` on the <a> tag makes complete area clickable.

Comment: `pointer-events: bounding-box` is a new value in SVG 2. Be aware that it may not work in all browsers yet.

Comment: I suspect that's only supported in Chrome at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Robert I will try to do a cross-browser test.